# Anime Club Event: Come watch anime with us this weekend!

Tags: discussion, community-events

The weekends can get a bit slow here, so let's have an event this weekend! During the first Saturday (UTC) of this month, I'd like to invite members of our community and their friends to come watch some anime together.

Tentative name: The Basement Cellar Anime Club Cinema.

The steams will be done via the [Rabb.it](http://rabb.it/Krazer) using official sources such as Amazon Prime video, Netflix, Crunchyroll, and Funimation, where available. The format will be loose and friendly, and will last all day, so anyone can hop in and out at any time. Some potential titles to stream are:

- *Full Metal Panic: Fumoffu*
- *Mushishi*
- *Space Battleship Yamato 2199* + movie
- *Bodacious Space Pirates* + movie

Last week, we had a pilot session to test bandwidth and video/audio connection. We went through *Patema Inverted*, *Time of Eve*, and the entire first season of *Full Metal Panic!*

Those with an ADSL-equivalent connection speed should be fine. There are three video quality settings you can toggle based on your connection bandwidth, HD, SD, LD (being the lowest resolution). Video chat will be disabled, but you are free to use audio chat if you so prefer.

The session will extend to Sunday as well, where the topic is free. You can binge as much as you want as long as you want. Stocking up on snacks and drinks is recommended.

The start of the session and the currently playing series will be announced in our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) as well as our LINE group (give you LINE ID in chat for an invite). Request and recommendations will be taken all day Sunday. Come and have fun with us this weekend!

Please leave any feedback of the event here so we can assess if we should make this a more regular event. Also if you have a better name suggestion for the event, please leave it here as well.

Comment: What timezone do you base "all day" on? considering i am in Australia and the US generally a day behind me

Comment: I do mention UTC time.

Comment: oh, missed that